# RGB Autoencoder outputs blank images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am working on a college assignment, the assignment is to make a denoise autoencoder to encode and decode images with noise.
I've implemented everything right but when trying to predict it outputs white images.

layers:

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
encoded = x
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
decoded = layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
s = 20 * 5000
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(0.01, s, 0.1)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule), loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
autoencoder.summary()
```

load data:

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = cifar100.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 32, 32, 3))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 32, 32, 3))
x_train = x_train[:5000]
x_test = x_test[6000:7000]

noise_factor = 0.2
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape)
x_test_noisy = x_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_test.shape)
x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)
```

fit and predict:

```
autoencoder.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True)
decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_test_noisy)

for i in range(5):
    # Display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 5, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test_noisy[i])
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    # Display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 5, i + 1 + 5)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i])
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The generated output could be due to max pooling, it reduces the dimensionality of images by reducing the number of pixels in the output from the previous convolutional layer.Kindly try changing the model like below.

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
encoded = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
decoded = layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```

Please find the complete code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/baa92670f182d5b5216e638314682403/74791909.ipynb). Thank you!